# calculate billing for twilio subaccount usage

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, twilio-api, twilio-php

I need to get last month's usage for a specific twilio subaccount.
I tried as specified in the official documentation, 
I am getting a response when passing Master Account's Sid and Auth Token However, I can't get any details when passing the subaccount Credentials.
Here's the code I tried out.

```
$sid    = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$token  = "your_auth_token";
$twilio = new Client($sid, $token);

$calls = $twilio->calls
                ->read(array("startTime" => new \DateTime('2018-1-15')));

foreach ($calls as $record) {
    print($record->sid);
}
```

Comment: I tested this code with one of my subaccounts and it works, if your $sid and $token are for a subaccount and you don't get any records back, check that you have indeed calls for that subaccount (look at the call logs in Twilio's console for that subaccount and assigned phone numbers).

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of [Twilio RecordSource](https://www.twilio.com/docs/usage/api/usage-record?code-sample=code-last-months-usage-for-all-usage-categories&code-language=PHP&code-sdk-version=5.x) and pass CategoryEnum as `TotalPrice`

```
$sid = "ACXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
$token = "your_auth_token";
$categoryEnum = "total_price"
$client = new Client($sid, $token, $categoryEnum);
```

In C#

```
TwilioClient.Init(SID, AuthToken);
DateTime currentDate = DateTime.Now;
DateTime startDate = new DateTime(currentDate.Year, currentDate.Month, 1);
var twilioPrice = (await RecordResource.ReadAsync(twilioSubAccount.SID, 
        category: RecordResource.CategoryEnum.Totalprice,
        startDate: startDate,
        endDate: startDate.AddMonths(1)))
        .FirstOrDefault();
```